# Create docker with gui for selenium

Tags: python, docker, user-interface, selenium-webdriver

I have an program, that takes information from database, go to the website and do some commands. I'm using selenium and I need to run it not in headless mode

Let's cut the program:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )


driver.get('https://google.com')

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
print('Test done')
```

What I need to write in dockerfile to run this ?

This is my try:
I.

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget unzip gnupg2


RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable


RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -q -O - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) \
    && wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
    && rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

WORKDIR /app
COPY main.py requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

error:

```
2023-07-26 12:39:59 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
2023-07-26 12:39:59     driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
2023-07-26 12:39:59     super().__init__(
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
2023-07-26 12:39:59     super().__init__(
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
2023-07-26 12:39:59     self.start_session(capabilities)
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
2023-07-26 12:39:59     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
2023-07-26 12:39:59     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2023-07-26 12:39:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
2023-07-26 12:39:59     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2023-07-26 12:39:59 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
2023-07-26 12:39:59   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2023-07-26 12:39:59   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2023-07-26 12:39:59 Stacktrace:
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #0 0x55cb45ef94e3 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #1 0x55cb45c28c76 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #2 0x55cb45c51d78 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #3 0x55cb45c4e029 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #4 0x55cb45c8cccc <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #5 0x55cb45c8c47f <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #6 0x55cb45c83de3 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #7 0x55cb45c592dd <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #8 0x55cb45c5a34e <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #9 0x55cb45eb93e4 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #10 0x55cb45ebd3d7 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #11 0x55cb45ec7b20 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #12 0x55cb45ebe023 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #13 0x55cb45e8c1aa <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #14 0x55cb45ee26b8 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #15 0x55cb45ee2847 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #16 0x55cb45ef2243 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59 #17 0x7f6861704fd4 <unknown>
2023-07-26 12:39:59
```

II.

Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget unzip gnupg2

# Install Chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Install ChromeDriver
RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -q -O - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) \
    && wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
    && rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

# Additional configuration to allow Chrome to run in headless mode
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Set up the XVFB server for running Chrome in headless mode
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset &

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python script and requirements file to the container
COPY main.py requirements.txt ./

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the Python script
CMD ["xvfb-run", "python", "main.py"]
```

and it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution, all I need is to set new version of headless mode

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be some issues with your Docker file.

I have made some changes to your Dockerfile, it might work:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip gnupg2

# Install Chrome and additional required libraries
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \xvfb

# Install ChromeDriver
RUN CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -q -O - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) \
    && wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver \
    && rm chromedriver_linux64.zip

# Set up the XVFB server for running Chrome in headless mode
ENV DISPLAY=:99
RUN Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset &

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python script and requirements file to the container
COPY main.py requirements.txt ./

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the Python script
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Changes made in the Dockerfile:

1. I combined the installation of additional required libraries (fonts)
   along with the installation of Chrome to minimize the number of
   separate apt-get commands.
2. Removed the xvfb-run command from the CMD because we are now running
   the Xvfb server as part of the Dockerfile.
3. We set the ENV DISPLAY=:99 to set the display environment variable
   required for running Chrome in headless mode.
4. The Xvfb server is started with Xvfb :99 ... and runs in the
   background.
5. The CMD ["python", "main.py"] is left unchanged, as this is the
   command to run your Python script.

I hope with these changes, your Docker container might now be able to run in headless mode.

Ah! Also, make sure your '*main.py*' script and '*requirements.txt*' are in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

You can check [this](https://gist.github.com/matt-bertoncello/a7296c4fc6cdbb8424ffa26b2b9b9257) for furthur reference.